# Cast from RawByteString to string does automatically invoke UTF8Decode?

Tags: delphi, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I want to store arbitary binary data as BLOB into a SQlite database.

The data will be added as `value` with this function:

```
procedure TSQLiteDatabase.AddParamText(name: string; value: string);
```

Now I want to convert a `WideString` into its UTF8 representation, so it can be stored to the database. After calling `UTF8Encode` and storing the result into the database, I noticed that the data inside the database is not UTF8 decoded. Instead, it is encoded as AnsiString in my computer's locale.

I ran following test to check what happened:

```
type
  {$IFDEF Unicode}
  TBinary = RawByteString;
  {$ELSE}
  TBinary = AnsiString;
  {$ENDIF}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  original: WideString;
  blob: TBinary;
begin
  original := 'ä';
  blob     := UTF8Encode(original);

  // Delphi 6:   Ã¤ (as expected)
  // Delphi XE4: ä  (unexpected! How did it do an automatic UTF8Decode???)
  ShowMessage(blob);
end;
```

After the character "ä" has been converted to UTF8, the data is correct in memory ("Ã¤"), however, as soon as I pass the `TBinary` value to a function (as `string` or `AnsiString`), Delphi XE4 does a "magic typecast" invoking UTF8Decode for some reason I don't know.

I have already found a workaround to avoid this:

```
function RealUTF8Encode(AInput: WideString): TBinary;
var
  tmp: TBinary;
begin
  tmp := UTF8Encode(AInput);
  SetLength(result, Length(tmp));
  CopyMemory(@result[1], @tmp[1], Length(tmp));
end;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  original: WideString;
  blob: TBinary;
begin
  original := 'ä';
  blob     := RealUTF8Encode(original);

  // Delphi 6:   Ã¤ (as expected)
  // Delphi XE4: Ã¤ (as expected)
  ShowMessage(blob);
end;
```

However, this workaround with `RealUTF8Encode` looks dirty to me and I would like to understand why a simple call of `UTF8Encode` did not work and if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Ansi versions of Delphi (prior to D2009), `UTF8Encode()` returns a UTF-8 encoded `AnsiString`.  In Unicode versions (D2009 and later), it returns a UTF-8 encoded `RawByteString` with a code page of `CP_UTF8` (65001) assigned to it.

In Ansi versions, `ShowMessage()` takes an `AnsiString` as input, and the UTF-8 string is an `AnsiString`, so it gets displayed as-is.  In Unicode versions, `ShowMessage()` takes a UTF-16 encoded `UnicodeString` as input, so the UTF-8 encoded `RawByteString` gets converted to UTF-16 using its assigned `CP-UTF8` code page.

If you actually wrote the `blob` data directly to the database you would find that it may or may not be UTF-8 encoded, depending on how you are writing it. But your approach is wrong; the use of `RawByteString` is incorrect in this situation. `RawByteString` is meant to be used as a procedure parameter only. Do not use it as a local variable. That is the source of your problem. From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.RawByteString):

> The purpose of RawByteString is to reduce the need for multiple
>   overloads of procedures that read string data. This means that
>   parameters of routines that process strings without regard for the
>   string's code page should typically be of type RawByteString.
>
> RawByteString should only be used as a parameter type, and only in
>   routines which otherwise would need multiple overloads for AnsiStrings
>   with different codepages. Such routines need to be written with care
>   for the actual codepage of the string at run time.

For Unicode versions of Delphi, instead of `RawByteString`, I would suggest that you use `TBytes` to hold your UTF-8 data, and encode it with `TEncoding`:

```
var
  utf8: TBytes;
  str: string;
...
str := ...;
utf8 := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);
```

You are looking for a data type that does not perform implicit text encodings when passed around, and `TBytes` is that type.

For Ansi versions of Delphi, you can use `AnsiString`, `WideString` and `UTF8Encode` exactly as you do.

Personally however, I would recommend using `TBytes` consistently for your UTF-8 data. So if you need a single code base that supports Ansi and Unicode compilers (ugh!) then you should create some helpers:

```
{$IFDEF Unicode}
function GetUTF8Bytes(const Value: string): TBytes;
begin
  Result := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Value);
end;
{$ELSE}
function GetUTF8Bytes(const Value: WideString): TBytes;
var
  utf8str: UTF8String;
begin
  utf8str := UTF8Encode(Value);
  SetLength(Result, Length(utf8str));
  Move(Pointer(utf8str)^, Pointer(Result)^, Length(utf8str));
end;
{$ENDIF}
```

The Ansi version incurs more heap allocations than are necessary. You might well choose to write a more efficient helper that calls `WideCharToMultiByte()` directly.

In Unicode versions of Delphi, if for some reason you don't want to use `TBytes` for UTF-8 data, you can use `UTF8String` instead. This is a special `AnsiString` that always uses the `CP_UTF8` code page. You can then write:

```
var
  utf8: UTF8String;
  str: string;
....
utf8 := str;
```

and the compiler will convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8 behind the scenes for you. I would not recommend this though, because it is not supported on mobile platforms, or in Ansi versions of Delphi (`UTF8String` has existed since Delphi 6, but it was not a true UTF-8 string until Delphi 2009). That is, amongst other reasons, why I suggest that you use `TBytes`. My philosophy is, at least in the Unicode age, that there is the native `string` type, and any other encoding should be held in `TBytes`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very helpful answer! I am using `WideCharToMultiByte` now which is a performant solution. I also learned that the new elements in `StrRec` - which includes the codepage. This explains why my `CopyMemory` hack in the original post did work as workaround.

Comment: Btw, an interesting fact is that the 2 calls of `WideCharToMultiByte` (one for determing the output size and one for the actual convertion) are faster than doing a single `UTF8Encode` with manipulating `StrRec.codePage` in memory (instead of invoking `SetCodePage` which would do an unnecessary `UniqueString`) - I know that this would be a dirty hack, but I wanted to test if I can be still faster than the WinAPI. Maybe I also did something wrong during the experiment.

Comment: You can do it with one call to WideCharToMultiByte. Take a look at how GetBytes is implemented for UTF8 encoding. Uses over allocation followed by down size.

Comment: In XE4's implementation, `TUTF8Encoding.GetMaxByteCount` returns `(CharCount + 1) * 3;` . I am not sure if this is safe, since RFC3629 specifies the maximum number of bytes per character to 4. I think they have chosen 3 because they assume that no real-world string needs 4 drawn through the whole string. So, it could be possible to create a string which cannot be converted using `TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes`. I see the conflict: multiplying everything with 4 would mean large memory usage if the input string is very large. This is why my first attempt was to use 2 calls of the API, which is slower.

Comment: That's 3 times the number of UTF-16 elements rather than 3 times the number of Unicode code points. Points outside BMP take two UTF-16 elements to encode. The 3 times is correct.

Comment: On reflection two calls and one allocation may well be faster than one call and two allocations. Prob depends on input. If you care, time with realistic data.

Comment: Why two allocations? If I shorten the string/array using `SetLength` to the actual length, the data will not be relocated.

Comment: There's no guarantee of that. The memory manager could very well move the data if it chose to do so. In any case, there will be overhead.